# get instance of bean within a sessionscope via session.getAttribute

Tags: jsf-2, jboss-weld, servlet-3.0

Within my (JSF, Servlet 3.0) sessionscope there are instances of classes. How can I get the instance of a class by using the names provided in sessionscope?

For example, in my session there is a instance of MyBean:

```
classes-ManagedBean-class com.MyBean=Bean: Managed Bean [class com.MyBean] with qualifiers [@Any @Default @Named]; Instance: com.MyBean@40a6d41f
```

In java code, I want to retrieve the actual instance of MyBean:

```
HttpSession session = us.getHttpSession();
MyBean mybean = (MyBean) session.getAttribute("???");
```

Which value should I provide for '???'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this what you after :

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
MyBean mybean =  (MyBean) context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("myBean");
```

Note that myBean is the name of the managed bean

for example `@ManagedBean(name = "myBean ")` , if no `(name = "myBean ")` is specified the default will be the same as class name with first letter in lower case

Comment: Yes, normally this would work. But I am using weld and hence the instance cannot be retrieved by this

Comment: have you looked at `getSessionMap()` , take a look what keys and values are there... might give you a hint

Answer (score 0):

The above is retrieved from SessionMap. I made a workaround by putting a key explicitly in sessionmap again. Now it works